# Image picker wallet style stack of images

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm still relatively new to Flutter so this problem might be obvious. What I want to do is create an apple wallet style stack of images using the image_picker package. I have a working example, but the behavior is not consistent. The cards are unique in that there is only two (i.e, one for drivers license, and one for insurance card)

Here is an image of what I mean

[image: Here is an image of what I mean]

I'm trying to create this such that based on which card you tap, that's the one that gets updated. I have a feeling I'm doing it incorrectly/inefficiently.

There's a lot to unpack here, so I've also included a [git repo](https://github.com/awatson32/image_stack) with the working example. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Image Stack Example'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  File? driversLicense;
  File? insuranceCard;
  String? base;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      bottom: false,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.topCenter, children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 50,
                child: insuranceCard == null
                    ? _buildDefaultCard('Insurance Card')
                    : _imageCard('insurance-card', 'Insurance Card',
                        _buildInsuranceCard()),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  top: 120,
                  child: driversLicense == null
                      ? _buildDefaultCard('Driver\'s License')
                      : _imageCard('drivers-license', 'Driver\'s License',
                          _buildDriversLicense())),
            ]),
          )),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDefaultCard(String title) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue.shade900, width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
        width: 330,
        height: 220,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
          child: ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              _buildImageSourceActionSheet(context, title);
            },
            iconColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
            textColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
            title: Text(title),
            minLeadingWidth: 6,
            trailing: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget _imageCard(String tag, String title, Widget child) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return SimpleDialog(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              elevation: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              children: [
                Hero(tag: tag, child: child),
                Center(
                  child: TextButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue.shade900)),
                    child: Text('Edit',
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .subtitle1!
                            .copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      _buildImageSourceActionSheet(context, title);
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          }),
      child: child,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildInsuranceCard() {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      child: Image.file(
        File(insuranceCard!.path),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
        height: 250,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDriversLicense() {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      child: Image.file(
        File(driversLicense!.path),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
        height: 250,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _selectImage(source, title) async {
    final XFile? _image =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: source, maxHeight: 250, maxWidth: 300);
    if (_image != null) {
      setState(() {
        if (title == 'Insurance Card') {
          insuranceCard = File(_image.path);
        } else {
          driversLicense = File(_image.path);
        }
        final List<int> bytes = driversLicense!.readAsBytesSync();
        base = base64Encode(bytes);
      });
    }
  }

  void _buildImageSourceActionSheet(BuildContext context, String title) {
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      showCupertinoModalPopup(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => CupertinoActionSheet(
                title: Text(title),
                cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                  child: const Text('Cancel'),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                ),
                actions: [
                  CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        _selectImage(ImageSource.camera, title);
                      },
                      child: const Text('Camera')),
                  CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        _selectImage(ImageSource.gallery, title);
                      },
                      child: const Text('Gallery'))
                ],
              ));
    } else {
      showModalBottomSheet(
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15))),
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => Wrap(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      _selectImage(ImageSource.camera, title);
                    },
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 16),
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.camera),
                    title: const Text('Camera'),
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    thickness: .75,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        _selectImage(ImageSource.gallery, title);
                      },
                      contentPadding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, bottom: 10),
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.collections),
                      title: const Text('Gallery')),
                  ListTile(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      tileColor: Colors.grey,
                      title: const Text('Cancel', textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                ],
              ));
    }
  }
}
```